# A concept Matrix<T> requires member function T::transpose() to return type satisfying the same concept

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

How can inside requirements of a concept, use the same concept?
Is this possible somehow?

```
//template<typename T> concept Matrix;    // it does not work

template<typename T>
concept Matrix = requires(T t)
{
    {t.transpose()} -> Matrix;   // return the same concept but I get "Matrix does not name a type"
    //t.transpose();             // workaround
};
```

Comment: A concept is not a type and there is nothing in c++ which can "return a concept". How do you want to write the function "transpose" that it will return a concept? Is it simply the wrong wording? Do you want that a function returns a type which also match a given concept?

Comment: @Klaus yes of course. It does not return a concept, but it returns a type `S` which satisfy the concept `Matrix<S>==true`. But `S` it can be different type from `T`.

Comment: Please correct your question to the correct wording, this will help to get an answer :-)

Comment: Now you are trying to create an infinite loop... Even if it could be valid with a helper.

Comment: (not answer). Isn't constraint on transpose a little too much? I mean, you do not need to add every statement to constraint...

Comment: @appleapple yes it is too much. I just wondering. `transpose()` also is too much for `Matrix`.

Comment: @simre I think I understand what you mean infinite loop. So it is not possible.

Comment: Could it be that you misunderstand concepts?

`t.transpose() -> T` would be my guess of what you want. When you give it some type `Matrix`, it should return the exact same type when you call `mat.transpose()`

Comment: Put yourself in the shoes of the compiler. Here's this type, T. Is T a matrix? Well, let's look if it has Transpose. Great, it does. But is the return type of it, T1, a matrix? Well, let's look if it has Transpose. Great, it does. But is the return type of it, T2, a matrix? Well, let's look if it has Transpose. Great, it does. But is the return type of it, T4, a matrix? Well, let's look if it has Transpose. Great, it does. But is the return type of it, T5, a matrix? Well, let's look if it has Transpose. Great, it does. But is the return type of it, T6, a matrix? Well, let's look if it has Tran

Comment: @Raildex it'd not work if dimension is part of signature.